# Python Unpickling When Some Modules are not Installed

Tags: python, module, pickle

Here's the situation.

- Computer A

  - Pickle dumps objects of different data types (built-in and not), including `scikit-learn` objects
- Computer B

  - Does not have `scikit-learn` installed and it doesn't have to be installed
  - Pickle loads -> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

Is there a way to ignore this error and still successfully load the pickle file by, for example, replacing objects that depend on modules not installed with `None` or skipping them? Of course I could simply not include `sklearn` objects in the pickle file, but I'm wondering if the code in Computer B can be robust against this situation.